# simple blog with croogo

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I is not What is the problem, I made a simple blog in Croogo, the problem is it is not adding or modifying or delete, because Arabic language ??

```
function add in controller
`public function admin_add() {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Add Part'));
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Part->create();

            if ($this->Part->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Part has been saved'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));//, $this->Part->id));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Part could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
            }
        }
    }`
```

=> 
model

```
    `class Part extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Part';

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Market' => array(
      'className' => 'Market',
      'foreignKey' => 'market_id',
    )
  );

    protected $_displayFields = array(
        'id',
        'num_part',
        'prix_part',
        'prop_Pledge',
        'prix_Pledge',

    );
}
```

`
add view

```
    <?php $this->extend('/Common/admin_edit'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Part');?>
<fieldset>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#role-main"><span><?php echo __('Part'); ?></span></a></li>
            <?php echo $this->Layout->adminTabs(); ?>
        </ul>

        <div id="role-main">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->label('num_part', 'العدد :  '); 
            echo $this->Form->input('num_part',array('label' => false ));

            echo $this->Form->label('prix_part', 'االمبلغ :  ');
            echo $this->Form->input('prix_part',array('label' => false ));

            echo $this->Form->label('prop_Pledge', 'إقتراح التعهد :  ');
            echo $this->Form->input('prop_Pledge',array('label' => false ));

            echo $this->Form->label('prix_Pledge', 'مبلغ التعهد :  ');
            echo $this->Form->input('prix_Pledge',array('label' => false ));
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->Layout->adminTabs(); ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="buttons">
<?php
    echo $this->Form->end(__('Save'));
    echo $this->Html->link(__('Cancel'), array(
        'action' => 'index',
    ), array(
        'class' => 'cancel',
    ));

?>
</div>
```

message error : The requested address was not found on this server.

Comment: line added to the database successfully but does not retoure to index it displays an error message

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is because of Arabic language because when you do :

```
        echo $this->Form->label('prop_Pledge', 'إقتراح التعهد :  ');
```

The second parameter is a text. I don't know which Cake version you're using but I think that the first field should be Part.prop_Pledge (Cake v3).

I suggest you to try to use debug() and exit to see where is the real problem or try to put remove arabic characters to see if this is the reason of you're problem.

- Just a question where is your $this->Form->create()  in view ?

> line added to the database successfully but does not retoure to index
>   it displays an error message

Could you print the message error hello21 please ?

Hope this will help you.